# composer require symfony/assets installation

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

I'm relatively new to pimcore and struggle to get the right composer packages.

First of all, I installed pimcore

```
composer create-project pimcore/skeleton my-project
```

I added TWIG to the project cause it is recommended for symfony. --> so i can use the asset function. [Symfony Asset](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html)

Now to include files, i would like to use the asset function of symfony. But sadly "asset()" does not return any path at the moment.

```
{# the image lives at "public/images/logo.png" #}
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="Symfony!"/>
```

So i realized, i have to install the asset package. But whenever i try to add the requirement, I get a error. I am not sure if i need to put the requirement in the composer.json file of the pimcore project, oder the composer.json file of the symfony/symfony package. Nevertheless I get errors in both cases:

**Result Update composer.json in the project root**

```
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove pimcore/pimcore v6.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install pimcore/pimcore v6.8.1
    - symfony/symfony v3.4.43 conflicts with pimcore/pimcore[v6.8.1].
    - symfony/symfony v4.4.11 conflicts with pimcore/pimcore[v6.8.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.2
    - Installation request for pimcore/pimcore (locked at v6.8.1, required as ~6.8.0) -> satisfiable by pimcore/pimcore[v6.8.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/asset v5.1.1
    - pimcore/pimcore v6.8.1 requires symfony/symfony ^3.4.26 || ^4.1.12 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v4.4.15, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.16, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9].
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.26
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.27
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.28
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.29
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.30
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.31
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.32
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.33
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.34
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.35
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.36
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.38
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.39
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.40
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.41
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.42
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.44
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.45
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.46
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.12
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.1.13
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.0
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.1
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.10
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.11
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.12
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.2
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.3
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.4
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.5
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.6
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.7
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.8
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.2.9
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.0
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.1
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.10
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.11
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.2
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.3
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.4
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.5
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.6
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.7
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.8
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.3.9
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.0
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.1
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.10
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.12
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.13
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.14
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.15
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.16
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.2
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.3
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.4
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.5
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.6
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.7
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.8
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.9
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|remove symfony/symfony v4.4.15
    - don't install symfony/asset v5.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.15
    - Installation request for symfony/asset ^5.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/asset[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**Result Update composer.json of the symfony package (/vendor/symfony/symfony) -
But I think this is the wrong one**

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - don't install symfony/asset 5.x-dev|remove symfony/symfony No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)
    - Installation request for symfony/asset 5.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/asset[5.x-dev].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Sorry for this silly question.
Thank you for helping me.

---

Edit 1:
This is my composer.json file for the project

```
{
"name": "pimcore/skeleton",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "pimcore/pimcore": "~6.8.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "cache/integration-tests": "^0.16.0",
    "codeception/codeception": "~2.4.5"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "": ["src/"],
      "Pimcore\\Model\\DataObject\\": "var/classes/DataObject",
      "Pimcore\\Model\\Object\\": "var/classes/Object",
      "Website\\": "legacy/website/lib"
    },
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-create-project-cmd": "Pimcore\\Composer::postCreateProject",
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::postInstall",
      "@pimcore-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::postUpdate",
      "@pimcore-scripts",
      "Pimcore\\Composer::executeMigrationsUp",
      "@pimcore-scripts"
    ],
    "pimcore-scripts": [
      "Pimcore\\Composer::clearCache",
      "Pimcore\\Composer::installAssets"
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "merge-plugin": {
      "include": [
        "composer.local.json"
      ],
      "recurse": true,
      "replace": true,
      "merge-dev": true,
      "merge-extra": false,
      "merge-extra-deep": false,
      "merge-scripts": false
    }
  }
}
```

---

Edit 2:

This was the command i used:

```
composer require symfony/asset
```

Comment: Are you following a tutorial?  The asset function in question is actually a twig extension and is part of the Symfony framework.  If you go to an empty directory and just do "composer require symfony/asset" you won't find any kind of twig interface.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/asset.html  I am not familiar at all with pimcore so I could easily be wrong.

Comment: yes, I added twig to the project and already use it.

Comment: The actual asset function is in a package known as the [Symfony twig-bridge](https://github.com/symfony/twig-bridge).

Comment: Can you share more details? What does `Update composer.json of the project` mean? What does `Update composer.json of the symfony package` mean? Does the later one mean that you try to edit files in the vendor folder?

Comment: @NicoHaase of the project means the root composer.json. and the symfony means the one in the vendor folder. I don't think i should touch the one in the vendor folder, but I did not know what else to do.

Comment: And **what** have you changed in the `composer.json`?

Comment: @NicoHaase command - composer require symfony/asset

Comment: Please also share the **exact** error message. Usually, Composer provides more details about the reason why a package could not get required

Comment: @NicoHaase I updated the error messages. thx alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've come to the point where it get's interesting: as the error message tells you, `symfony/symfony` is already installed (as this is a dependency of `pimcore/pimcore`). This core package contains all components of Symfony, and installing a single additional component (like `symfony/asset`) is not possible.

If you can use the posted image tag (`<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="Symfony!"/>`) without any error message popping up during rendering (in terms of: the markup can be generated, even if the image's source is not generated as expected), this also means that the Twig extension needed for the `asset` function is installed.

So, the next step for you is searching for the asset configuration that is missing to generate the proper image URL.

Comment: ok, so I looked at it from the wrong angel. Now i just have to check where i can config this assets path for a local website.

Comment: That happens from time to time :)